# Extend the Element prototype

Tags: javascript, html

I really want to extend the interface `Element` in my personal JS library.

For example,

```
class ElementWrapper extends Element {
   constructor(){
      super();
   }
}
```

Does not work, because `Element` is an interface not a class (that's my guess..).

I don't mind hackish ways, but so far I've had no luck. I thought maybe I could do something like this

```
for(let k in Element.prototype){
    ElementWrapper.prototype[k] = Element.prototype[k];
}
```

but this also does not work (`Illegal invocation`)

Is there any way to extend `Element` ?

Comment: Yes, use [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components).

Comment: Wow... ! I can't believe I had written (twice now) my own library called "Template" which does exactly this. Oh my..